# How to check API access log in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

How to check API access log in kubernetes.
I have an application with two pods. I want to see the access logs how it is getting distributed.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

Comment: Logging is an application specific function though. You'll need to provide more context of your app deployment and how it logs to get an answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your architecture. Unfortunately, the question is not complete, so we can provide only general info here.

The common way [acessing logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in Kubernetes is through `kubectl logs <pod_name>` command. That'll give you logs for the first container on that Pod. It's needed to specify particular container name if you are running some side-car containers there.

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                           READY   STATUS
nginx-65f88748fd-scxzl         1/1     Running

kubectl logs nginx-65f88748fd-scxzl
<Nginx Logs from my pod>
```

Additionally (if your app supports internal logging) it is possible to connect to the Pod in interactive mode and run some command directly on pod (if supported).

`kubectl exec <parameters> <pod_name> -- <command>`

For example you can run some shell on Pod and check logs.

```
kubectl exec -it nginx-65f88748fd-scxzl -- bash
root@nginx-65f88748fd-scxzl:/#
```

`-it` initiates connection in interactive mode and command to run is placed after `--` .

Hope that helps.